# Please recommend resources on philosophy of physics

Tags: resource-recommendations

please suggest reading on the philosophy of physics and also whatever thoughts/comments you may have for somebody interested in philosophical aspects of physics and the relation of philosophy and physics.

Comment: I would probably suggest a slightly broader approach. I would look at certain particular concepts, such as logic, causality, entropy, "the arrow of time", and so on. I think you should also try and develop your own view of mathematics and how it developed and that it is based on axioms which are considered to be "obviously true". The fact that applications have caused the development of mathematical fields is quite important (like the Dirac delta function). The book by Davis/Hersh "The Mathematical Experience" is good. And I remember reading "The Three Cultures" by Kagan.

Comment: And I find dynamics and the different concepts of stability really helpful. Since we basically live in a dynamic world.

Answer (score 2):

Julian Barbours book *The End of Time* discusses the role of time in physics and whether it is an emergent - what we observe is not time, but change and motion.

Aristotles *Physics* & *Metaphysics* might sound like an odd choice given that Aristotle gets something of a bashing from Susskind, Weinberg and a whole host of others. Generally, though, they are attacking a straw man and not  what Aristotle himself wrote. It's worth pondering that well over two millenia ago, that philosophers were discussing that motion was problematic, the role of determinism and indeterminism in nature, and whether chance was causal. This is unsettling when we realise it's only recently that Newtonian determinism was overthrown.

Also the essay *Early Greek Thought and Perspectives for the Interpretation of QM: an Ontological Approach* by Verelst & Coecke. This is available on the [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0611064) and is also included in a volume of essays on the intersection of Art, Philosophy & Physics - *The Blue Book of Einstein meets Magritte*.

Answer (score 1):

The [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/) is a good resource. It's not exclusively about physics, but has a lot of relevant entries (searching for physics returns more than 700 hits).